# Is it necessary to upgrade Google Play Service to latest version

Tags: android, performance, google-play-services

I have open a project that is using `android.gms:play-services:9.0.1`, this version is around 2 years old. I have a task to upgrade these services with latest version.

But what can go wrong if i don't updates these services. I googled the expiration date of `android.gms:play-services`, but no expiry/depreciation is provided anywhere.

My Question is how long can we keep using the older version of play service library, and what can go wrong if we don't update these service. As i am seeing some code changes, if i update these services to latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never know what can go wrong as with each new update they deprecate few classes and add few new classes.

You can see [release notes](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#april_12_2018_-_version_1500) of each play service versions. Though you are not having a problem right now you might run into it in case you update your target version and studio or gradle versions.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you do not know for sure when you can have a problem. I think you could try to use the old version for some time though and see if everything goes okay. 
The worst is that some codes can conflict and cause serious problems. I always try to update as soon as update comes. You could try this: https://anderbot.com/en/android/apps/?id=air.android.app.watchmanager. It may help you to know if new update is coming and if it can cause any damage. I use it for some time so I can say it worth your attention.

But still if everything works properly you can use the old version. Just be careful and attentive.